# keep reading myself

Tags: structure

I would like to inquire about the structure "**keep reading myself**". Is it an idiom? What its origin? and what it exactly means?

The motivation behind my question is the following story:
I got results for some analyses, I was unable to fully understand the findings. I sent these findings to my assistant who is a native English speaker. He emailed me back:

> Thank you for sending these results. I could not understand the findings as well! I will keep reading myself and update you when I find additional information.

It seems here that "keep reading myself" means that I will keep reading and reviewing materials until I find new information, then I will update you.

Googling "keep reading myself "yielded very little number of results, so it seems not a common structure? Is this an actual usage of English?

Comment: Please use code formatting (four spaces) only where absolutely necessary: It has no line breaks, so users on mobile devices can only read whatever fits on their screen. With quotes (>), the problem does not appear.

Comment: "Myself" used in this sense more or less interchangeable with "personally", isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is poorly worded.

"Myself" can be used for emphasis "I myself will do it" means "I (and not somebody else) will do it." Also "I will do it myself" suggest that "I will do it without help from someone else".

This is the structure that is used here "I will keep reading" with emphasis on "I". However the information doesn't really need emphasis, and if the object of "reading" is omitted it becomes possible to interpret "myself" as a reflexive pronoun, making the sentence ambiguous. Thus it is poorly worded. The context (an email) makes this acceptable, but I'd be surprised to see something like this in a proofread book.

There is rarely a need to use myself as an intensifier see this [forum discussion](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/78427-When-to-use-I-myself) for example.

Comment: thank you so much! indeed it is poorly worded. I am not a native speaker, but I speak and read English for more than twenty years. I never read this structure.

Comment: @goro In the extremely unusual case where somebody has been tattooed with a large amount of text, it might actually be accurate for them to say, "I will keep reading myself." ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford I was going to suggest a fortune teller doing their own crystal ball gazing

Answer (score 3):

It is just another way of saying:

> I, myself, will keep reading and update you when...

That is, for my part, I will continue to read it and will update you when...

Comment: Thank you for the response! I totally agree about the meaning. I am just wondering why it is not commonly used in articles, books, or in Google?! Is it an American English or british or Australian?

Comment: Google doesn't capture every word spoken on the planet.  No, this is not restricted to a single dialect.

Comment: Thanks again! Even the meaning of "reading myself" is not mentioned in any dictionary !

Comment: There is no reason to link those two words! Almost any verb could go there in place of **reading**. For example:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keep%20going%20myself%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en In dictionaries of your own language, do you have an entry for **singing myself** or whatever the equivalent is?

Comment: You need to read about **REFLEXIVE PRONOUN**. as "intensive" pronouns.

Comment: The structure of your sentence "I, myself, will keep reading and ..." is much clearer!!

Comment: Well, it may be because you're not a native speaker and you recognize only what you know and understand. All that is strange to a learner is not strange to a native

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, I think it could be a way of saying that the speaker will be reading, in addition to a previously-mentioned person who will also be reading. For example:

> Could you do some reading about this? I will keep reading myself and update you when I find additional information.

Or:

> I've asked Paul to do some reading about this. I will keep reading myself and update you when I find additional information.

I don't think that the above usage is poorly worded, but it is confusing in print. In speech with the right intonation (emphasis on "myself"), it would be less confusing.

If there was no such context, then the only other way I would interpret it is as an awkward phrasing meaning "alone, without help", which would be better phrased as:

> I will keep reading **by** myself and update you when I find additional information.

Either way, it's not an idiom, just using "myself" as an ordinary reflexive pronoun.

Comment: This.  Context can make the odd become sensible.  A couple sentences around OPs example text would definitely have helped the question.

Comment: It's not actually the *wording* that's poor (necessarily), it's the *punctuation*. If you put a comma before and after *myself*, then it makes more sense.